# Using a navigation property as discriminator in a TPH inheritance scenario in Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework-4, single-table-inheritance

I am trying to create a TPH inheritance hierarchy using foreign keys / navigation properties as discriminators and I am having some trouble getting it right.

I have the following entities:

```
Person:
  Id (int)
  Name (nvarchar)
  PlaneId (int)
  CarId (int)

Car:
  Id (int)
  Name (nvarchar)

Plane:
  Id (int)
  Name (nvarchar)
```

with `PlaneId` and `CarId` beign FKs. I have corresponding tables in a database and I can create a conceptual model using the VS2010 EF wizard. The `Person` entity then has two navigation properties, `Car` and `Plane`.

Now I want to derive two types from Person:

```
Pilot (condition: PlaneId is not null)
Driver (condition: CarId is not null)
```

So, I add the entity Pilot, tell it to map to Person and add the condition `PlaneId is not null`. At this point Visual Studio (or edmgen I guess) complains that the property `Person.PlaneId with 'IsNull=false' condition must be mapped`.

What is my next step? I have tried various approaches, but can't seem to get it to work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. [Discriminator columns must be non-nullable](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/24380ee6-4753-46a2-a3ed-b1cb2e2d161c).